# Tell browser that there's a banner blocking the top portion of the screen?

Tags: html, css

I've got a site with a banner sitting on top of the content.

```css
.content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.floating-banner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="floating-banner">
    testing
  </div>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br>
  Place the top button just beneath the testing banner, set focus to the bottom
  button, then hit shift+tab to put focus onto the top button. It'll remain invisible
  due to being beneath the banner.
  <button>top button</button>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
  <button>bottom button</button>
</div>
```

I'd like if I could "tell" the browser that when a keyboard navigation occurs it should know to scroll if the focused element is within the top 400px (or any arbitrary size).

Also note that I unfortunately can't use a sticky positioned header in this case.

Comment: Add `padding-top: 200px` to your `.content` or to the entire `body`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your javascript file

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  if (event.shiftKey && event.key === "Tab") {
    const focusedElement = document.activeElement;
    const contentContainer = document.querySelector(".content");
    const contentRect = contentContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
    const focusedRect = focusedElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    const scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || 
    document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    const focusedTopRelativeToContent =
      focusedRect.top - contentRect.top + scrollTop;

    if (focusedTopRelativeToContent < 400) {
      contentContainer.scrollTop -= 200; // Adjust as needed
    }
  }
});
```

This listens for the Shift + Tab key combination and checks if the focused element is within the top 400px of the `.content` container. If it is, it scrolls the container to ensure the focused element is visible.